# Change Object Columns to Boolean

Tags: python

I'm importing data where my boolean fields are coming in as objects. All I'm trying to do is check to see if a value of True or False exists in the column and if it does, change the column type to boolean. Tried the following, but doesn't work:

```
for col in df:
    if len(df[(df[col] == True) | (df[col] == False)]) > 0:
        df[col] = df[col].astype('bool')
    else:
        pass
```

Probably not the best way of doing it either, but was quick and dirty. If someone can help fix this or come up with a more efficient solution, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
for col in df:
    if df[col].isin([True,False]).any():
        df[col] = df[col].astype('bool')
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Why ```else: pass```?